# How can i use another url If i get url(' ')

Tags: javascript, php, url

I'm a novice and I'm writing this one, but if there is no image on the source, then I have just empty space.

Could someone please tell me how can I get ***/images/no-image.jpg*** if I'm getting ***background-image: url();***

This is my code:

```
<div class="uk-clearfix uk-position-relative">
    <div class="recipebanner">              
          <div class="recipeimg uk-position-cover" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $recipe->picture; ?>); background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 50%;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use ternary icon `background-image: url(<?php echo ($recipe->picture) ? ($recipe->picture) : 'no-image.jpg' ;?>)`

Comment: Try this  add ah  `width,height` of style

Comment: @HappyCoding Than you very much Sir ! Your solution works just fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer which works for my case is:
Please use ternary icon background-image: url(picture) ? ($recipe->picture) : 'no-image.jpg' ;?>) –  by @HappyCoding -thank you!

Thanxx all!

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. Try this out:

```
url(<?php if(file_exists($recipe->picture)) echo ($recipe->picture) else echo 'no-image.jpg'; ?>)
```

Pass correct image path to **$recipe_picture** variable.

Comment: It brings me Fatal error & syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE), expecting ',' or ';'... 
am i did smthng wrong?

<div class="recipeimg uk-position-cover" style="background-image: url(<?php if(file_exists($recipe->picture)) echo ($recipe->picture) else echo 'images/no-image.jpg'; ?>); background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 50%;"></div>

Comment: background-image: url(<?php echo ($recipe->picture) ? ($recipe->picture) : 'no-image.jpg' ;?>) – by @HappyCoding worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($recipe)) {
    echo $recipe;
} else {
    echo $no_picture;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! 
Here i need to add more code to have $no_picture; 
background-image: url(<?php echo ($recipe->picture) ? ($recipe->picture) : 'no-image.jpg' ;?>) – by @HappyCoding worked for me!